# Where of these two places to set authorised Ad Account IDs for the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My goal is to add third party Ad Account IDs I need to access using the reportstats and insights APIs. (My developer account is at 'Basic' access so this is still a requirement.) I can see this being set in two places and I don't know what the difference is between them.

Here I can add the Ad Account Ids directly to the 'Authorised Ad Account IDs' input field:
[image]

But if I click on the "Ads API" button in the pop up I can also add Ad Account IDs, and these two places do not seem to be in sync with each other.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are for different purposes

The first screenshot, with the 'Authorized Ad Account IDs' field designates advertising accounts that you want to be able to run ads promoting your Facebook app - a user who isn't an admin or developer of your app will be able to create ads about your app if they do so in one of those accounts

The second screenshot is specific to apps which themselves access ad accounts via the Marketing API - for apps with 'Development' or 'Basic' [access to the Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) you may only access a limited set of accounts, and this UI is where you specify which accounts you want to manage (otherwise any single user of your app could have so many accounts that they push you over the limit)